# zsh within juypter notebook not recognizing any commands

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I have confirmed and ran it on my local terminal but it will not recognize any commands in juypter notebook for some reason...

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6QkV.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block and/or error message in the body of question instead of a screenshot. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9170226) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

1. First, please confirm that jupyter has been installed correctly.

> ```
> pip3 install --upgrade pip
> pip3 install jupyter
> ```

2. Find the installation location of jupyter

> ```
> pip3 show jupyter
> ```

You will get a result similar to the following
[image]

According to location, we can find the location of jupyter

> ```
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/
> ```

3. Then add this location to the path searched by the command. (Be careful not to add spaces on both sides of the equal sign when assigning)

> ```
> vim ~/.zshrc (or .bashrc if bash)
> ```

4. Add the following statement

> ```
> export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/:$PATH
> ```

5. Then reload the relevant command

> ```
> source.zshrc
> ```

6. Use jupyter

> ```
> jupyter notebook
> ```

Hope this helps you